# How does the Ubuntu license work for commercial use? Do we have to follow the LGPL or the GPL?

Tags: 11.10, 11.04, proprietary, license, open-source

I have an Ubuntu computer. Once Ubuntu starts I use my applications, such as: driving school exams, learning, practical use, and studying.

Now, I am preparing license documentation. If I use Ubuntu commercially, what license do I have to apply?

1. I have not changed any of Ubuntu's source code.
2. I've installed Ubuntu and I use for commercial purposes.
3. My Ubuntu installation will be used for teaching driving in Europe.
4. When Ubuntu starts, it starts my application to teach drivers and give them exams and practice. They can also return the box for new exams and updates.

What happens for with regard to the license terms when I sell such PCs with embedded Ubuntu and my application pre-installed? (They use x11vnc, vim, gcc, etc. and many other tools but no source code is modified. I wrote my application in BASH, PHP, and Java)

Comment: You should also study Canonical's trademark policy at http://www.ubuntu.com/aboutus/trademarkpolicy

Comment: fyi, recently Canonical's message on commercial IP licenses were discussed here; "Ubuntu, Canonical, and IP – jonobacon@home" http://www.jonobacon.org/2015/08/28/ubuntu-canonical-and-ip/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Ubuntu has no *one* license - every file may have a different license.

That shouldn't be a problem for you as long as *you* don't (re)distribute the files. As long as the binaries are supplied by Ubuntu (Canonical) the license conditions apply to them, not you.

I am not a lawyer, so I couldn't comment on what happens when you simply pass along the files, but I suggest you either *do* find the legal answer to that, or else have your customers install the OS themselves.

In the case of GPL and LGPL software, your obligations include providing an offer to produce source code when asked (for a limited time). In practice, it would be sufficient to point your customers at the Ubuntu source provisions, but to be absolutely sure, you would have to ensure that you had your own copy (I mean, what happens if Ubuntu's servers vanished? Also, remember that their time limit dates from when they gave the files to you, but yours would date from when you passed them along, some time later.)

Answer (score 1):

looking here 
http://www.ubuntu.com/project/about-ubuntu/licensing

Comment: Whilst this may theoretically answer the question, [it would be preferable](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/8259) to include the essential parts of the answer here, and provide the link for reference.